# tor processname / Service name would tor run?

Tags: windows

Under which process name would tor run and would there be any differnce between browser and or relay?

Would there also be a installed windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor should always be starting as `tor.exe` on Windows, or `tor` on Unix'y systems.

You can also [create a service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#NTService), which will be called "Tor Win32 Service". You will need to run:

```
tor --service install
```

or for extra options,

```
tor --service install -options -f C:\tor\torrc [Option Value]
```